# getelementbyid list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementbyid

I'm trying to create a loop that will put values from inputs in an array.
The point is that I have 81 inputs and their ids are "`cells-[x]`".

What I tried to do is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = [];
    for(i=0;i<80;i++){
        test[i]=(document.getElementById('cell-[i]').value);
    }
</script>
```

but it's not working.

B.T.W, I might have made a mistake in the for loop itself, but it is not my point(i'm only a beginner).

Comment: Your `test` variable doesn't need an iterator unless you want 81 variables. Do `var test = document.getElementById('cell-' + i).value`

Comment: You can also use Template Literals implemented into ECMAScript 6 standards. `var test = document.getElementById(\`cell-${i}\`).value`

Comment: What happens if you add an 81st element? Most of us think about this the other way around: generically get a list of nodes (`HTMLInputElements`) and iterate over those. Food for thought.

Comment: Use modern JS template strings. You're very close, the syntax just wasn't right: `getElementById(`cell-${i}`)` instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You have been tricked by SO code recognition. `getElementById(\`cell-[${i}]\`)`

Comment: so I have. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

**1.** Your `'cell-[i]'` is all in a string, so each time it thinks you're taking the value: `'cell-[i]'`. Replace your parameter in `getElementById` with:

```
('cell-[' + i + ']').
```

**2.** Try:

```
test.push(document.getElementById('cell-[' + i + ']').value)
```

That should do it.

Comment: I don't agree with #2. `test[i]` will find the index of `test` and set the value correctly. You do not *have* to use `push`. `push` is mainly good for dynamically appending an element to an array. However, the method OP is using will suffice.

Comment: @TyQ. - But the array is blank by default and doesn't have any indices initially, which is why you have to push them. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily. The array may be blank but JS is nothing like languages such as C++. You don't have to specify what value an array has at a specific index. Try this in Chrome console: `var arr = []; arr[15] = 5; console.log(arr[15]);`

Comment: @TyQ. - Never mind! You're right - I'll modify my response. I didn't know that originally, thanks Ty!

Comment: Spent like 5 minutes constantly re-reading my answer double checking everything, gets downvoted, *delete*. lmao i suck at using this site. Your answer is simple and works just as mine .. should have.. Upvoted. :)

Comment: No worries Ty, everyone learns something here and we appreciate all the collaboration :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addEventListener` for the form and call the custom function `getValues()` which will get the values for all the inputs. You can use the [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to collect all the inputs once regardless of what their `id` is, and then loop over them using [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use [**`.push()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add values to the array that we will use to collect the input values.

See a demo below try adding values to input and hit submit button

```js
//get all the inputs 
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

// valArray used to collect the values of input
var valArray = [];
//function to get the values of the form inputs
function getValues() {

  //loop the aray using foreach
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {

    //use array.push() to add the values to the custom array of input values
    valArray.push(input.value);

  });

}
//add submit event listner for the form
document.querySelector("#my-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //stop form from submitting
  getValues();
  console.log(valArray);
});
```

```html
<form name="my-form" id="my-form">
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```